# sqlite3_prepare not ok in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have the following code inside a .m file and i can get to where NSLog says OK BEFORE PREPARE but i cant get to NSLog OK INSIDE PREPARE.  What is wrong with the if statement line that is not working?  I know i have an sqlite database.  I do have a table called school. It has one row of data in the school table.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    arrayOfSchools = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [[self schoolTableView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self schoolTableView]setDataSource:self];


    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if(sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &eduLogDB)==SQLITE_OK){
        [arrayOfSchools removeAllObjects];

        NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM school"];

        const char *query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"OK BEFORE PEPARE");
        if(sqlite3_prepare(eduLogDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"OK INSIDE PREPARE");

            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW){
                NSString *schoolName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)];


                School *school = [[School alloc]init];
                [school setSchoolName:schoolName];


                [arrayOfSchools addObject:school];


            }
        }

    }
    [[self schoolTableView]reloadData];

}
```

Comment: What does sqlite3_errmsg say?

Comment: Try `sqlite3_clear_bindings(statement);
    sqlite3_reset(statement);` before if statement